# PHPmailer attachment image file send without saving file

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPmailer
first I save my image bo_image directory. and the following code is

```
$uploaddir = 'bo_image/';
$bank_statement = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['bank_statement ']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bank_statement ']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

then I am sending it using PHPmailer

```
$mail->addAttachment($bank_statement);
```

But i want to send an email with an attachment without saving. that means it's sent automatically from my website.

Comment: use PHPMailer function `AddStringAttachment()` to attach the file without saving it.

Comment: It's correct to call `move_uploaded_file`, but you need to check the return value to be sure it's worked before continuing.